# Regex global replace with Groups

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked high and low for an example of how to implement a Regex global replace in C# where there are Groups involved, but I've come up empty.  So I wrote my own.  Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex re = new Regex(@"word(\d)-(\d)");
    string input = "start word1-2 filler word3-4 end";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int beg = 0;
    Match match = re.Match(input);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        // get string before match
        output.Append(input.Substring(beg, match.Index - beg));

        // replace "wordX-Y" with "wdX-Y"
        string repl = "wd" + match.Groups[1].Value + "-" + match.Groups[2].Value;
        // get replacement string
        output.Append(re.Replace(input.Substring(match.Index, match.Length), repl));

        // get string after match
        Match nmatch = match.NextMatch();
        int end = (nmatch.Success) ? nmatch.Index : input.Length;
        output.Append(input.Substring(match.Index + match.Length, end - (match.Index + match.Length)));

        beg = end;
        match = nmatch;
    }
    if (beg == 0)
        output.Append(input);
}
```

Comment: Please explain _exactly_ what you are trying to achieve. In particular, inputs and wanted outputs.

Comment: Basically, I was just trying to write an algorithm that could be applied to a given string and replace all occurrences of a match (with its Groups values) globally (i.e., throughout the entire string).  It's too bad there's not a "global" enum you could pass to Replace to effect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx). It's a delegate that takes a [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) and returns the string you want to replace it with.

e.g.

```
string output = re.Replace(
    input,
    m => "wd" + m.Groups[1].Value + "-" + m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Alternatively, and I'm less sure about this, you could use *lookahead* - "check that this text follows, but don't include it in the match". The syntax is `(?=whatver)` so I think you'd need something like `word(?=\d-\d)` and then just replace it with `wd`.

Comment: Your first solution is exactly what I was hoping for!  One line to replace my whole 'while' loop.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you're reading too much into this.  There's nothing in the question or the accompanying sample code to indicate that a MatchEvaluator is necessary.  In fact, the problem he's trying to solve doesn't really exist: the [Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) **is** global.

Comment: @Alan I missed the simple use of `$` in the replace that Guffa's shown, but _some_ form of backreference (or lookahead) is needed here.

Comment: @Alan The problem as I saw it was "how do I do a non-trivial regex replace without needing to get a match, build my replacement string with results from the match, and then do a `string.replace` with the result" - the ability to do it globally drops out nicely when that is fixed.

Comment: That's what I meant by *reading too much into it*.  You saw that great mass of code and you naturally assumed the author was trying to do something tricky.  But as it turned out, the problem *was* trivial: the OP just hadn't read the API docs well enough.

Comment: You're all right -- the problem was trivial and I obviously had not read the API docs well enough.  Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Alan tbh it's more me not knowing the API well enough either. The last question like this I saw required some int parsing of the captures so the evaluator was necessary; in this simpler problem I didn't realise there was an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do any logic at all, that replacement can be done using group references in the replacement string:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"word(\d)-(\d)", "wd$1-$2");
```